# Python search dictionary keys for search input

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.x

So here's my question:

I want to search a dictionary to see if any key contains a user-inputted keyword. For example, the user searches for John.

```
elif option == 3:
        count = 0
        found = None
        search_key = input("What do you want to search for? ").lower()
        for key, val in telephone_directory.items(): #takes each element in telephone directory
            if search_key in key: #checks if it contains search_key
                if found is None:
                    found = val
                    count = 1
                if found is not None:
                    print(" ")
                    print("More than one match found. Please be more specific.")
                    print(" ")
                    count = 2
                    break

            if found is None:
                print("Sorry, " + str(search_key) + " was not found.")
                print(" ")
                function_options() #redirects back

            if found is not None and count < 2:
                print(str(search_key) + " was found in the directory.")
                print("Here is the file on " + str(search_key) + ":")
                print(str(search_key) + ":" + " " + telephone_directory[search_key])
                print(" ")
                function_options() #redirects back
```

So this is where I am right now. Whatever the search may be, even if it is the entire key, it returns "was not found". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I want want to do some matching on a part of the name, you should expect the case where multiple returns are possible. What should happen in such a case ?

Comment: I'll add a case where if it brings up more than 2 it will ask the user to be more specific. Not a big problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make a few choices; allow multiple matches, find only the first match, or only allow for at most one match.

To find the first match, use `next()`:

```
match = next(val for key, val in telephone_directory.items() if search_key in key)
```

This will raise `StopIteration` if no match was found; return a default instead or catch the exception:

```
# Default to `None`
match = next((val for key, val in my_dict.items() if search_key in key), None)

try:
    match = next(val for key, val in telephone_directory.items() if search_key in key)
except StopIteration:
    print("Not found")
```

These versions will only loop over the dictionary items until a match is found, then stop; the full `for` loop equivalent would be:

```
for key, val in telephone_directory.items():
    if search_key in key:
        print("Found a match! {}".format(val))
        break
else:
    print("Nothing found")
```

Note the `else` block; it is only called when the `for` loop was allowed to complete, and was not interrupted by a `break` statement.

To find *all* matching keys, use can use a list comprehension:

```
matches = [val for key, val in telephone_directory.items() if search_key in key]
```

Finally, to allow for only one match, efficiently, use two `next()` calls on the same iterator, and raise an error if a second match is found:

```
def find_one_match(d, search_key):
     d = iter(d.items())
     try:
         match = next(val for key, val in d if search_key in key)
     except StopIteration:
         raise ValueError('Not found')    

     if next((val for key, val in d if search_key in key), None) is not None:
         raise ValueError('More than one match')

     return match
```

Adapting that to the `for` loop approach again, would require you to break only if a second item is found:

```
found = None
for key, val in telephone_directory.items():
    if search_key in key:
        if found is None:
            found = val
        else:
            print("Found more than one match, please be more specific")
            break
else:
    if found is None:
        print("Nothing found, please search again")
    else:
        print("Match found! {}".format(found))
```

Your version doesn't work because you print 'not found' for *each and every key* that doesn't match. You can only know that you didn't match a key until the very end when you've iterated over all the keys in your dictionary.

Comment: Only allow for one match. If multiple matches, ask user for more input (more specific search). Thanks though! And can you write them out in blocks instead? Srry, beginner!

Comment: but why doesn't it work the way I initially put it? Shouldn't it?

Comment: but why does the for loop need to have val there too? I'm just searching the keys...

Comment: when i run it the way I have it above, it returns not found even if the entire key is typed in

Comment: Ah, python 3, of course, adjusted. You could just loop over the dictionary directly if you only want the keys (use `.keys()` still if you need an iterator for the `find_one_match` method); I presumed you wanted to find the entry *connected* to the key.

Comment: well, yeah. I want to search through the dict first, find if the key is there, if it is, print the info associated with it. First comes finding it though. The trouble is that each key is 2 words, and I want the associated key to come up even if 1 word is typed.

Comment: Without more detail about your data and what word you typed in, it's hard to say why it goes wrong for you. The code above works in the general case.

Comment: say I type in John. And there is a key in the entry for John Peters. I want John to satisfy the case of found, for John Peters.

Comment: and the above code prints both more than one match and match found

Comment: @AristidesMilios: "the above code" is a little ambiguous by now, don't  you think? :-) I've tested all the snippets, updated where needed.

Comment: I have it so that it returns "more than one match found" if 1 or more matches are found. i think it is some sort of progress, but it still isn't working like it should

Comment: I will, even though I answered my own question with the actual working version.

Comment: Note that the `else:` on my loop does just the same thing; if `found` is set when `else:` is executed, you have found only one entry. Otherwise, nothing was found. The `break` for a second entry ensures this.

Comment: yeah the main problem is that for some unfathomable reason I replaced the else with if found is not None, which made both if statements be executed.